# How to make the size of my window automatically adjust with size of the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

To start, I am making an interactive personal website that allows people to view different parts of my resume by flying around a little rocket and going through different portals.

Here is my HTML code,

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Space Ship</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        canvas{
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        body{
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <canvas id="game"></canvas>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the javascript code,

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('game');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(255,255,255,.6)";

// Constants in objects doesnt work cause objects passing as reference and will by modified!
// If you want constant constant, use primitives
const SPACESHIP_SIZE = { width: 15, height: 25 };
const SPACESHIP_POSITION = { x: window.innerWidth/2, y: window.innerHeight/2};
const GRAVITY = 1;
const HOVER_TICKS = 20;
//Update thrust constant
const THRUST = 15;

const Systems = {
    'main': {
        holes:[
            {x: window.innerWidth/8, y: window.innerHeight/3, size: 40, dest: 'Education'},
            {x: window.innerWidth/8, y: window.innerHeight/1.15, size: 40, dest: 'Technical Skills'},
            {x: window.innerWidth/2, y: window.innerHeight/3, size: 40, dest: 'Experience1'},
            {x: window.innerWidth/2, y: window.innerHeight/1.15, size: 40, dest: 'Experience2'},
            {x: window.innerWidth/1.1, y: window.innerHeight/3, size: 40, dest: 'Contact Me'},
        ]
        
    },
    'Education': {holes:[{x: window.innerWidth-100, y: window.innerHeight-100, size: 40, dest: 'main'}]},
    
    'Technical Skills': {holes:[{x: window.innerWidth-100, y: window.innerHeight-100, size: 40, dest: 'main'}]},
    
    'Experience1': {holes:[{x: window.innerWidth-100, y: window.innerHeight-100, size: 40, dest: 'main'}]},
    
    'Experience2': {holes:[{x: window.innerWidth-100, y: window.innerHeight-100, size: 40, dest: 'main'}]},

    'Personal Projects': {holes:[{x: window.innerWidth-100, y: window.innerHeight-100, size: 40, dest: 'main'}]},
    
    'Contact Me': {holes:[{x: window.innerWidth-100, y: window.innerHeight-100, size: 40, dest: 'main'}]},
    
};

let spaceShip;
let currentSystem = 'main';
const spaceObjects = [];

class SpaceObject {
    constructor(size, position, color = 'black', angle = 0) {
        this.color = color;
        this.size = size;
        this.position = position;
        this.angle = angle;
        spaceObjects.push(this);
    }
    tick() {
        this.update();
        this.draw();
    }
    update() {}
    draw() {}
    isAbove({x, y}) {
        return Math.abs(this.position.x - x) < this.size && Math.abs(this.position.y - y) < this.size;
    }
    destroy() {
        spaceObjects.splice(spaceObjects.indexOf(this), 1);
    }
}

class SpaceShip extends SpaceObject {
    constructor(size, position) {
        super(size, position, 'yellow');
        this.aboveHole = 0;
        this.engineOn = false;
        this.rotatingLeft = false;
        this.rotatingRight = false;
        this.velocity = {x: 0, y: 0};
    }

    draw() {
        const triangleCenterX = this.position.x + 0.5 * this.size.width;
        const triangleCenterY = this.position.y + 0.5 * this.size.height;
        ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(triangleCenterX, triangleCenterY);
        ctx.rotate(this.angle);
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.beginPath();
        // Triangle
        ctx.moveTo(0, -this.size.height / 2);
        ctx.lineTo(-this.size.width / 2, this.size.height / 2);
        ctx.lineTo(this.size.width / 2, this.size.height / 2);
        ctx.closePath();

        ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fill();

        // Flame for engine
        if (this.engineOn) {
            const fireYPos = this.size.height / 2 + 4;
            const fireXPos = this.size.width * 0.25;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(-fireXPos, fireYPos);
            ctx.lineTo(fireXPos, fireYPos);
            ctx.lineTo(0, fireYPos + Math.random() * 100);
            ctx.lineTo(-fireXPos, fireYPos);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fillStyle = 'orange';
            ctx.fill();
        }
        ctx.restore();
    }

    update() {
        this.moveSpaceShip();
        this.checkAboveHole();
    }

    moveSpaceShip() {
        // Angle has to be in radians
        const degToRad = Math.PI / 180;
        // Change the position based on velocity
        this.position.x += this.velocity.x;
        this.position.y += this.velocity.y;
        // Move spaceship to other side when leaving screen
        this.position.x = (canvas.width + this.position.x) % canvas.width;
        this.position.y = (canvas.height + this.position.y) % canvas.height;
        /*
         Adding floating point numbers to the end of the
         rotaion handling to make roation faster
         */
        if (this.rotatingLeft) this.angle -= (degToRad+.15);
        if (this.rotatingRight) this.angle += (degToRad+.15);


        // Acceleration
        if (this.engineOn) {
            this.velocity.x += (THRUST / 100) * Math.sin(this.angle);
            this.velocity.y -= (THRUST / 100) * Math.cos(this.angle);
        }
        // Update the velocity depending on gravity
        this.velocity.y += GRAVITY / 2500;
    }

    checkAboveHole() {
        const hole = spaceObjects.find(spaceObject => spaceObject !== this && spaceObject.isAbove(this.position));
        if(hole) {
            this.aboveHole++;
            if(this.aboveHole > HOVER_TICKS) {
                confirm(`Jump to system ${hole.dest}?`) && jump(hole);
                this.aboveHole = 0;
            }
        } else {
            this.aboveHole = 0;
        }
    }
}


const circle = (ctx, x, y, radius, color = 'white') => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
};

class BlackHole extends SpaceObject {
    constructor(size, position, dest) {
        super(size, position);
        this.dest = dest;
    }
    update() {
        // Spin?
        this.angle+=.01;
    }
    draw() {
        // Shadow
        ctx.shadowBlur = this.size >>> 2;
        circle(ctx, this.position.x, this.position.y, this.size + 1, `rgba(255, 255, 255, .6)`);
        // Hole
        circle(ctx, this.position.x, this.position.y, this.size, this.color);
        // Spinning view
        circle(ctx, this.position.x + (this.size * Math.sin(this.angle) - 1), this.position.y + (this.size * Math.cos(this.angle) - 1), 2, 'gray');
        circle(ctx, this.position.x - (this.size * Math.sin(this.angle) - 1), this.position.y - (this.size * Math.cos(this.angle) - 1), 2, 'gray');
    }
}

function handleKeyInput(event) {
    const { keyCode, type } = event;
    const isKeyDown = type === 'keydown' ? true : false;

    if (keyCode === 37) spaceShip.rotatingLeft = isKeyDown;
    if (keyCode === 39) spaceShip.rotatingRight = isKeyDown;
    if (keyCode === 38) spaceShip.engineOn = isKeyDown;
}

function jump({dest}) {
    currentSystem = dest || 'main';
    while(spaceObjects.length) spaceObjects[0].destroy();
    Systems[currentSystem].holes.forEach(hole => new BlackHole(hole.size, {x: hole.x, y: hole.y}, hole.dest));
    spaceShip = new SpaceShip(SPACESHIP_SIZE, SPACESHIP_POSITION);
    
}

function draw() {
    // Clear screen
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 10, 60)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(150, 150, 150)';
    ctx.fillText(`--> You are in ${currentSystem}`, 40, 40);
    ctx.fillText(`--> Use the arrow keys to guide the rocket into different portals`, 40, 60);
    ctx.fillText(`--> Refresh the page if you resize your window`, 40, 80);
    
    
    //Adding section/system text information
    if(currentSystem=='main'){
        ctx.font ='bolder 20px Courier New'
        ctx.fillText('Education Portal', window.innerWidth/9, window.innerHeight/4);
        ctx.fillText('Technical Skills Portal', window.innerWidth/9.2, window.innerHeight/1.27);
        ctx.fillText('Experience Portal', window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight/4);
        ctx.fillText('Experience Portal', window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight/1.27);
        ctx.fillText('Contact Me', window.innerWidth/1.25, window.innerHeight/4);

    }
    if(currentSystem=='Education'){  
        //College
        ctx.font = 'italic 20px Courier New';
        ctx.fillText('Binghamton University, State University of New York, ', 50, 150);
        ctx.fillText('Thomas J. Watson College of Engineering and Applied Science', 50, 170);
        ctx.fillText('Bachelor of Science in Computer Science', 50, 190);
        
        ctx.font = '20px Courier New';
        ctx.fillText('Overall GPA: 3.92', 50, 210);
        ctx.fillText('Major GPA: 4.0', 50, 230);

        ctx.fillText('Relevant Coursework: Programming and Hardware Fundamentals,', 50, 270);
        ctx.fillText('Professional Skills, Ethics, and CS Trends,', 50, 290)
        ctx.fillText('Data Structures and Algorithms, Programming with Objects and Data Structures,', 50, 310);
        ctx.fillText('Architecture from a Programmer Perspective (By Fall 2021)', 50, 330);

        //High School
        ctx.font = 'italic 20px Courier New';
        ctx.fillText('Islip High School', 50, 430);
        ctx.fillText('STEM Academy Honors', 50, 450);
        ctx.font = '20px Courier New';
        ctx.fillText('Overall GPA: 100.77, Top 5% of class', 50, 470);

        ctx.fillText('Return', window.innerWidth-135 , window.innerHeight-155);

    }


    if(currentSystem=='Technical Skills'){
        ctx.font = '20px Courier New';
        ctx.fillText('Languages: Python, Java, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, C++',50 , 150);
        ctx.fillText('Software and OS: VS Code, Eclipse, Sublime Text, Git, Logisim, Anaconda,',50 , 190);
        ctx.fillText('Spyder, Microsoft Office, Linux, MacOS',50 , 210);
        ctx.fillText('Additional: Familiar with MySQL, Arduino',50 , 250);

        ctx.fillText('Return', window.innerWidth-135 , window.innerHeight-155);
    }


    if(currentSystem=='Experience1'){
        ctx.font = '20px Courier New';
        ctx.fillText('Binghamton University Rover Team, Software Engineer | Binghamton, NY',50 , 150);
        ctx.fillText('October 2020 - Prestent',50 , 170);
        
        ctx.fillText('-->Designed networks and code bases using C++ to maximize the efficiency',50 , 190);
        ctx.fillText('   and performance of a model mars rover for The Mars Society University',50 , 210);
        ctx.fillText('   Rover Challenge which takes place yearly', 50, 230);
        
        ctx.fillText('-->Built a custom username/password page by interfacing Google Firebase', 50, 250);
        ctx.fillText('   with a HTML, CSS, and JavaScript page which allowed for user', 50, 270);     
        ctx.fillText('   authentication, permitting members of the team to view classified documents', 50, 290);
        
        ctx.fillText('-->Prepared rover data by implementing Python script from scratch', 50, 310);
        ctx.fillText('   using Matplotlib and NumPy which led to data visualization to be analyzed', 50, 330);

        ctx.fillText('-->Constructed the GUI for the base station computer in C++ so', 50, 350);
        ctx.fillText('   that all the components of the rover could be viewed in the most effective way', 50, 370);
        

        ctx.fillText('JPMorgan Chase, Software Engineering Virtual Experience Program | Remote Role',50 , 460);
        ctx.fillText('July 2020 - September 2020',50 , 480);
        ctx.fillText('-->Modified an interface with a stock price data feed using Python 3 so that the system/data could be analyzed',50 , 500);
        ctx.fillText('-->Implemented the perspective open-source code in preparation for data visualization',50 , 520);
        ctx.fillText('-->Received certificate of completion by end of program',50 , 540);

        ctx.fillText('Return', window.innerWidth-135 , window.innerHeight-155);
    }


    if(currentSystem=='Experience2'){
        ctx.font = '20px Courier New';
        ctx.fillText('Google CSSI, Coursera, Software Engineering Student | Remote Role',50 , 150);
        ctx.fillText('June 2020 - August 2020', 50, 170);
        ctx.fillText('-->Selected to take part in an invite-only Google Tech Student Development program', 50, 190);
        ctx.fillText('-->Developed/designed personal web pages through CodePen using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript', 50, 210);
        ctx.fillText('-->Reviewed, designed, and implemented a green screen algorithm in JavaScript', 50, 230);
        ctx.fillText(' to transform images on our developed web pages', 50, 250);
        ctx.fillText('-->Learned to hide data in images through the use of steganography', 50, 270);
        ctx.fillText('-->Received certificate of completion by end of program', 50, 290);





        ctx.fillText('Return', window.innerWidth-135 , window.innerHeight-155);
    }


    if(currentSystem=='Contact Me'){
        ctx.fillText('Contact Me',50 , 450);
        ctx.fillText('Return', window.innerWidth-135 , window.innerHeight-155);    
    }






    //Loading small stars
    ctx.shadowBlur = 1;
    for (var i = 1, j = 1; j<canvas.height; i+=100, i > canvas.width && (i=1, j+=100), circle(ctx, i, j, 1));

    //loading medium stars
    ctx.shadowBlur = 2;
    for (var i = 1, j = 1; j<canvas.height; i+=150, i > canvas.width && (i=1, j+=150), circle(ctx, i, j, 2));

    //loading larger stars
    ctx.shadowBlur = 3;
    for (var i = 1, j = 1; j<canvas.height; i+=225, i > canvas.width && (i=1, j+=225), circle(ctx, i, j, 3));

    // tick all objects
    spaceObjects.forEach(spaceObject => spaceObject.tick());

    // Repeats
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

// Event Listeners
document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyInput);
document.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyInput);
// Start the game
jump({dest: 'main'});
draw();
```

So far I am fairly happy with how it looks, it's just that the formatting for things like text and the size of the window looks.

Here is what the website looks like once it is opened up in my browser.
[image: Picture of what the website looks like as of now.]

My issue is that when the user adjusts their window the, picture displayed does not automatically adjust in real time unless the user refreshes the webpage. Is there a solution to fix this? Similarly is there a way to make the text above each portal appear directly above each potal without hard coding where is should appear on screen? When the size of the picture changes, the text gets thrown off because it is hard coded and not relative to the portals. Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Did you get this worked out?

Comment: Not yet @Justin

Answer (score 2):

For resize use an event listener. You can place any functions that require to be called again here. This will merely resize the canvas.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', (e) => {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
})
```

And to align you text with your portals use the location of the portals as the x and y of the text. I subtract 50 from the y to place it above to portal. Also use  `ctx.textAlign = "center";`

```
if(currentSystem=='main'){
        ctx.font ='bolder 20px Courier New';
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.fillText('Education Portal', Systems['main'].holes[0].x, Systems['main'].holes[0].y - 50);
        ctx.fillText('Technical Skills Portal', Systems['main'].holes[1].x, Systems['main'].holes[1].y - 50);
        ctx.fillText('Experience Portal', Systems['main'].holes[2].x, Systems['main'].holes[2].y - 50);
        ctx.fillText('Experience Portal', Systems['main'].holes[3].x, Systems['main'].holes[3].y - 50);
        ctx.fillText('Contact Me', Systems['main'].holes[4].x, Systems['main'].holes[4].y - 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

So it seems what you need,  is media queries and css to make your site responsive to different 'screen' sizes.

About the text look for  flex-box or grid in google, a css solution should be easy to find something like https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html